# How to delete column in csv by using scala

Tags: scala

I had a csv file as module, and I need to delete a specific column which had a header.for example("apple" is the header).I want to delete all this column.How could I make it.Then make it to a new csv file.

Comment: And how are you processing this **CSV**? With `spark`, with `scio`, with `cormorant`, plain `scala`? - What have you tried?, What problems do you have?

Comment: Scala. I mean I just want to edit the cvs file but don't know how. Should I make a map or something for the column or row?

Comment: unfortunately, your question is simple _"too board"_ + _"opinion based"_. I would recommend you to use the Scala [**gitter**](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) or [**reddit**](www.reddit.com/r/scala) for such question. - My two cents would be, if you only want to remove some column and save the file: read ethernet file using `Source.fromFile`, then get an iterator of the lines using `getLines`, then remove the column from each line, probably using `split(",")` to get an array and then recreate the line. Finally save the iterator to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Scala but here's a quick scala script which may help.
It assumes your data is in `file.csv`.  It writes the data to standard output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala
import scala.io.Source
val lines = Source.fromFile("file.csv").getLines
for (header <- lines.take(1)) {
    val hcols = header.split(",")
    for (line <- lines)
        println(hcols.zip(line.split(",")).filter(_._1 != "apple").map(_._2).mkString(","))
}
```